# Sort dataframe in a function

Tags: r, sorting

I am trying to create a function which takes a dataframe and the columns by which I want to sort as arguments. This is what I have come up with:

```
sortDf <- function(df, columns){
  df <- df[order(df[,columns]),]
  return(df)
}
```

This is my usecase:

```
set.seed(24)
dataset <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5)
df <- as.data.frame(dataset)
sortedDf <- sortDf(df, c('V1', 'V2'))
```

How ever I get this as a result:

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
3     1  1  5  3  4
5     1  5  2  5  2
NA   NA NA NA NA NA
NA.1 NA NA NA NA NA
NA.2 NA NA NA NA NA
NA.3 NA NA NA NA NA
1     5  2  1  2  5
4     5  2  1  2  1
NA.4 NA NA NA NA NA
2    NA  4 NA  1  4
```

The dataframe is kinda sorted but where does the 'NA' come from and how can I remove them? What do I do wrong? I want to sort descending. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With order function you are ordering two columns as a unique vector with all the elements included on them. Is really that what you want?

Comment: If you just want the ability to do this then dplyr's arrange function already implements it. https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html#arrange-rows-with-arrange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a different function

```
 f1 <- function(dat, cols){
    dat[do.call(order, dat[cols]),]
}

f1(df, c("V1", "V2"))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#2  1  1  2  1  3
#1  1  5  3  5 NA
#5  3  1  1 NA  1
#4  3  4  4  3 NA
#3  4  4  4 NA  4
```

In the OP's code, the `order` is applied on a `data.frame` instead of a `vector`.  It can be used either separately or within `do.call` i.e.

```
df[order(df$V1, df$V2),]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#2  1  1  2  1  3
#1  1  5  3  5 NA
#5  3  1  1 NA  1
#4  3  4  4  3 NA
#3  4  4  4 NA  4
```

gives the same result as the OP's code.  So, either it columns can be individually mentioned (which would not be easy when there are more number of columns) or use `do.call`.

---

This can also be implemented using the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`) with `quosures`.  After taking the input vector, it is converted to `quosures` (`parse_quosures`) and then evaluated by unquoting (`!!!`) it in `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
f2 <- function(dat, cols){
    cols <- rlang::parse_quosures(paste(cols, collapse=";"))
    dat %>%
         arrange(!!! cols)
      }

f2(df, c("V1", "V2"))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1  1  1  2  1  3
#2  1  5  3  5 NA
#3  3  1  1 NA  1
#4  3  4  4  3 NA
#5  4  4  4 NA  4
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:5), 25, replace = TRUE), 5))
```